# Apache : logout from an LDAP authenticated session

Tags: session, logout, apache2.4, mod-ldap

I tried several possibilites to logout from a LDAP authenticated session. None of them worked. I use Apache 2.4 on Centos7.
Is there a way to do so?

My latest config look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:12345>

  Alias /logouttest /var/www/html/logouttest
  LogLevel trace
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common
  ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/error_log

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/logouttest

  <Directory /var/www/html/logouttest>
    AllowOverride all
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "logouttest"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ad.example.com:389/OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=xxxx,DC=ch?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectclass=*)
    AuthLDAPBindDN  CN=LDAPQuery,OU=services,OU=Administrative,OU=company,DC=xxxx,DC=com
    AuthLDAPBindPassword 'xxx'
    Require valid-user

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
    RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1,NS]
    RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-User %{RU}e

  </Directory>


  <Location "/logout">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
    #SetHandler form-logout-handler
    AuthFormLogoutLocation /logout/logout.html
    Session On
    SessionMaxAge 1
    SessionCookieName session path=/
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache doc confuses me in this subject. Especially the line `SetHandler form-logout-handler` doesn't work at all. (Do I have to write my own handler?).

Anyway, I'd be glad if someone can confirm whether it's possible to properly terminate authenticated sessions in apache (Some posts declare it as not possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of logging out for HTTP Basic Authentication. A request is either accompanied by your credentials, or it isn't -- nothing in-between. Your browser doesn't prompt you every time, but the credentials are xmitted every time.

The form-related stuff you've read about is for a set of session-oriented login modules.  It's n/a to what you have here.

Comment: Thanks covener. So how would you do it with a session? I tried this as well (see the config above).

Comment: Sorry, don't know specifically about mod_auth_form. In general, if a framework/programming model / appserver provides that capability, they provide an API to invalidate that session.